# MariaDB not starting after I've deleted ib_logfile

Tags: mariadb, galera

My MariaDB couldn't start and after a little research I've found out I should delete ib_logfile s in /var/lib/mysql to make it run.

so I moved ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 to another directory and after that when I attempt starting it, it gives me this error (I recopy them in /var/lib/mysql but nothing changed)

```
2023-09-05 19:16:37 140469467424896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace 107201 was not found at ./tstp_statistics/eir_statistics.ibd.
2023-09-05 19:16:37 140469467424896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Set innodb_force_recovery=1 to ignore this and to permanently lose all changes to the tablespace.
2023-09-05 19:16:37 140469467424896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Tablespace not found
2023-09-05 19:16:37 140469467424896 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2023-09-05 19:16:39 140469467424896 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2023-09-05 19:16:39 140469467424896 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-09-05 19:16:39 140469467424896 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-09-05 19:16:39 140469467424896 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2023-09-05 19:16:39 140469467424896 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I need the structure of my databases and tables and I can't risk deleting the whole /var/lib/mysql.

Another solution I found was "InnoDB force recovery mode" but I'm affraid it may result in losing data and structure.

How can I get those table structures?

Comment: What was the original error log with the iblog* files in place? Which MariaDB version? [Don't ever delete them](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/330567/restoring-old-raw-backup-in-mariadb-10-8-1-without-ib-logfile0/330568#330568) per answer provided to warn people again.

Answer (score 1):

The "little research" found out what you shouldn't do, NEVER DELETE ib_logfile* except where explicitly documented in official documentation after following it to the letter. Please give feedback to the providers of little research and tell them how broken it is to save the next person from such data loss.

Like [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/330567/restoring-old-raw-backup-in-mariadb-10-8-1-without-ib-logfile0/330568#330568) it's flawed and will loose data.

Move the "ib_logfile*" back and look closer at the original problem.

Well done on saving the files rather than just delete.